# Meteor compare elements in array

Tags: arrays, templates, meteor, permissions, roles

I'm just beginning the adventure of a meteor, so I have a little problem
The database structure looks like this:
users have roles, the roles have subroles. I want to check whether the user has at least one of the subrole, which is a function argument as an array.
Here's the code:

```
userHasAllPermissions: function(permissionArray) {
    var result = false;
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if (!user) return false;
    permissionArray = ["Permission 0", "Permission 1", "Permission 99999"];
    var rolesToSearch = _.keys(user.roles);
    for (var i = 0; i < rolesToSearch.length; i++) {
        var role = Meteor.roles.findOne({name: rolesToSearch[i]});
        var subrole = role.subRoles;
        for(var k = 0; k < permissionArray.length; k++)
        {
        if(_.include(_.some(subrole,permissionArray[k]))){
                result = true;
                console.log("Ok");
                break;
            }
            console.log("Error")
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, right off the bat:

- On line 5, you seem to be overwriting your `permissionArray` function argument. Are you sure you want to do that?
- Is user.roles an `Object` or an `Array`? I'd expect an array, but then `_.keys(user.roles)` doesn't make sense.
- It would be way more efficient to use the `$in` mongo query to get the subroles, you can then iterate over the resulting cursor. In fact, perhaps you can use two `$in` query operators to get your result right away: `Meteor.roles.find({name:{$in:rolesToSearch}, 'subRoles.$':{$in: permissionArray}})` It's hard to test this, but I'm guessing you can find a query like that - if it returns a result - should let your function return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

user.roles is Ocject, user.roles have Array of subRoles